# What's the point of defining a function to print something?

Tags: python

For example, in my Codecademy it says,

```
def spam():
    print ("Eggs!")
```

but I feel like you could just print Eggs! if you wanted without the def spam():

Somebody please help

Comment: Right. That's just a simple example showing how to write the simplest function. Akin to writing a "Hello World!" program. Its just to show how the def works. You wouldn't do just that in a real program.

Comment: You are correct. You'd have to ask the people who wrote the material what their intent was.

Answer (score 1):

But you could do:

```
def spam():
    print("Eggs!")
```

And then call `spam` a thousand times in your code. Now, if you want to change that to print `"Bacon!"` you only have to change it once, rather than a *thousand* times.

```
def spam():
    print("Bacon!")
```

Comment: I feel like this is a helpful answer but with Pycharm you could just refactor and rename to change all 1,000 at once as well

Comment: Or just "find and replace" in any half decent text editor, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Def helps to make your code reusable. In this case, we can think that it's useless indeed. But in other case, you'll want to be able to call a part of code multiple time !

Answer (score 1):

In this case you're right, there is no reason to create a function for just print, but when you get to more complex writing a function saves you a lot of precious time and space. For example I want to get a specific part of a .json with API, instead of writing all these lines again and again I will write it once and call it whenever I need it.

Comment: Alright, first of all, thanks for the answer. Second of all, I have no idea what a .json or API is. Third of all, with Pycharm you could just refactor and rename to change however many times you entered the variable

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Best practice would be to define the string once and call the function as many times as needed. It will be easier to maintain. Yes, you can find and replace all instances, but you risk accidentally changing more than you bargained for. Additionally, if you were working on a shared project and someone were to merge code after you made that change, you’d have to go back and update all their new code to reflect the change. If they had just been calling spam(), there’s no update needed post-merge.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it is for demonstration/illustration purposes. Once the code flow reaches the function, you'll get the message printed. Sometimes it is important to understand the sequence of calling the functions or just the fact that the function has been called.